# Oilfy in OpenCV

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, imagefilter

I am trying to implement **oilfy filter using openCV**, and I came across [this code](https://github.com/gitpan/Image-Filter/blob/master/Oilify/oilify.c).

The code uses [gd2 lib](http://libgd.github.io/pages/about.html). But as my application already uses OpenCV for image processing, its is not recommended to use another lib.

I couldn't understand what the following code does

```
for (y = 0; y < maskHeight; y++)
{
    for (x = 0; x < maskWidth; x++)
    {
        index = y * maskWidth + x;
        rTable[index] = (double) gdImageRed(imageptr,gdImageGetPixel(imageptr,w + x - maskWidth / 2, h + y - maskHeight / 2));
        gTable[index] = (double) gdImageGreen(imageptr,gdImageGetPixel(imageptr,w + x - maskWidth / 2, h + y - maskHeight / 2));
        bTable[index] = (double) gdImageBlue(imageptr,gdImageGetPixel(imageptr,w + x - maskWidth / 2, h + y - maskHeight / 2));
    }
}
```

Can someone, help me with understanding the oilfy algorithm or tell me how to convert the code into OpenCV?

Any openCV code for oilfy effect will be of much help.

Comment: Have you come across proper API documentation for gdImageRed, and  gdImageGetPixel?. Please let me know if you have come across the same.
Also `w + x - maskWidth / 2, h + y - maskHeight / 2` becomes -ve values initially. and I dont know what `gdImageGetPixel(imageptr, -5,-5)` will return!.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link -
https://libgd.github.io/manuals/2.2.3/files/gd-c.html#gdImageGetPixel

`gdImageGetPixel` returns the color value at that pixel in integer format.This contains combination of `RGB`. The pixel is indicated with `gdImagePtr object` followed by `x and y co-ordinates of the pixel` in the image.

`gdImageRed` returns the red color intensity value in that color, similarly `gdImageBlue` and `gdImageGreen`.